# To show that $\lim a_k=\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

To show that $\lim a_n=\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$ where $\lambda>0$.
Let $a_1=\frac{\lambda^{\lambda}}{(1+\lambda)^{\lambda+1}}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_1}{(1-a_n)^{\lambda}}$. For me is very difficult to find some recurtion to try of calculing the limit. For example my first attempt was:

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_1}{(1-a_n)^{\lambda}}=\frac{a_1}{(1-\frac{a_1}{(1-a_{n-1})^{\lambda}})^{\lambda}}$$ but i need to trasnformate i guesss the term $1-\frac{a_1}{(1-a_{n-1})^{\lambda}}=\frac{(1-a_{n-1})^{\lambda}-a_1}{(1-a_{n-1})^{\lambda}}$ but $\lambda $is not neccesary a integer, so i do know how to continuied.

Or perhasp i need to use other way as $|\frac{a_1}{(1-a_n)^{\lambda}}-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}|$ and boundeing for something that ges to $0$ but is difficult too. Please if somebody can to help me with hints, i will appreciate so much. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  Let $f(t)=\frac {a_1} {(1-t)^{\lambda}}$ for $t>0$. Check that $f$ is strictly increasing. If $a_n >a_{n-1}$ then  $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)>f(a_{n-1})=a_n$. Also, $a_2 >a_1$. It follows that $a_n$ is a bounded increasing sequence: For boundedness, show, using induction, that $0<a_n<\frac  1 {1+\lambda}$ for all $n$. Hence, $(a_n)$ has a  finite limit $l$. Now solve $l=\frac {a_1} {(1-l)^{\lambda}}$ to find the value of $l$.

Comment: I am working in the induction, thank you. $\frac{1}{(1-a_n)}<(\frac{1+\lambda}{\lambda})^{\lambda}$..i am stuck

Comment: Simplify $a_1/ \frac {\lambda} {(1+\lambda)^{\lambda}}$. @weymarandres

Comment: Thank you again, $a_1$ holds. I supossed for $n$ then for $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_1}{1-a_n}$. The other side, i have by induction hypothesis $a_n<\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$ then $1-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}<1-a_n$ then $(1-\frac{1}{1+\lambda})^{\lambda}<(1-a_n)^{\lambda}$ then $\frac{1}{(1-a_n)^{\lambda}}<\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{1+\lambda})^{\lambda}}=\frac{(1+\lambda)^{\lambda}}{\lambda^{\lambda}}$..i am stuckk sorry

Comment: You just forgot $a_1$ in the numerator of the given recurrence relation.  @weymarandres

Comment: Im so sorry, you lost me, Do i need prove that $a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$ but how i forgot the $a_1$. Sorry

Comment: I am not sure if i thought well, prove that $a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$ is equivalent to prove that $(1+\lambda)a_{n+1}<1$ is equivalent to prove that $(1+\lambda)\frac{a_1}{(1-a_n)^{\lambda}}<1$ is equivalent to $(1+\lambda)a_1<(1-a_n)^{\lambda}$ equivalent to $a_1<\frac{(1-a_n)^{\lambda}}{1+\lambda}$ and the last term is less than $1$ right? these implies that $a_1<1$ i am thinking right way? sorry

Comment: @weymarandres Why don't you use the induction hypothesis. That is very important. Use the fact that $(1-a_n)^{\lambda} >(1-\frac  1  {1+\lambda})^{\lambda}$.